# How to avoid stacked actionbar when including small tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

My problem is quite simple, however not sure if there is a clean/easy fix for this. I have an action bar with one tab. In some devices (motorola xoom) the tab is in the action bar, however in some other devices (Nexus 7, Samsung Galaxy 10 tablet), the stacked action bar shows up with the tab on it.

You can see from the picture below that the tab's text is small enough to for the tab to fit in the main action bar instead of spawning the stacked one...    I am using a regular action bar, but I've read through the internet that this also happens in Sherlock.

Is there any way to fix this without having to recur to a customView? I wouldn't really want to change all my implementation (tab listeners, etc), just to do this. Thanks in advance!

[image: App executed from a Nexus 7]